# Solve $\min_{x} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i(x_i) + g(x)$ $\ {\rm s.t.} Ax = b$; $x = [x_1,\ldots,x_N]^T$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

An optimization problem:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{  x \in \mathbb{R}^N }{\text{minimize}} 
& & \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i\left(x_i\right) + g(x) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & A x = b \ ,
%&&& X \succeq 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $x = [x_1,\ldots,x_N]^T$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$, and $f_i$ is $m$ strongly convex and $L$ smooth, and $g(x)$ is twice differentiable.

Question(s):

- How to solve such problem, say if $N \geq 10^{10}$? Can we use second-order method, e.g., Newton's method, for such large scale?
- (But I think for $N \leq 5000$ we can use Newton like method, right?)

I am sure there must be tons of methods to solve such problems. But I would be happy to hear few methods from you experts for my learning purpose.

ADD:
Constraint that $M \leq N$. So, $A$ is a fat matrix.

Comment: Maybe solving this problem in two steps?

Comment: Please suggest how to do it in two steps

Comment: If $rk(A)=N\leq M$ the unique solution to your system is $x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$ and so you do not have any degree of freedom left to minimize your objective function. If $rk(A)<N\leq M$ you may be able to use generalized inverses of $A$ to narrow down the set of solutions and at the same time eliminate the linear constraints.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that $rk(A) = M \leq N$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe solving this problem in two steps?
1) Add the "fictive" constraint $g(x) = y$ to your original problem and obtain the conditional solution $x^*(y)$.
EDIT: This gives:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{  x \in \mathbb{R}^N }{\text{minimize}} 
& & \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i\left(x_i\right) + y \\
& \text{subject to}
& & A x = b \text{ and } g(x) = y.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
which yields $x^*(y)$. Note that $A x^*(y) = b$ and $g(x^*(y))=y.$
2) Then, relax the "fictive" constraint and minimize over $y$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{  y \in \mathbb{R} }{\text{minimize}} 
& & \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i\left(x_i^*(y)\right) + y \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

This yields the overall solution(s) $x^{**}$, which also satisfy(ies) the requirement $y=g(x^{**})$.
For existence and unicity of the solution, however, it would be helpful to know a bit more about $f$ and $g$ (are they monotone, convex, single peaked?)
Of course, the equivalence between the one step and two step optimization procedure does not work in all situations. But under suitable assumptions on $f$ and $g$, they are equivalent.

Comment: What is $y$? And how is the constraint $Ax = b$ incorporated?

Comment: say $g(x) = \|z-x\|_^2$ then how $g(x) = y$ relate with $Ax - b = 0$?

Comment: See the EDIT lines which try to answer this point.

Comment: I am still not able to figure out. Say, I form the Lagrangian in step 1, that is $L(x(y),\nu) =  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i\left(x_i\right) + y + \nu^T \left(A x - b \right)$, then solve $\nabla_{x(y), \nu} L= 0$. Then obtain $x^*(y)$. After computing $x^*(y)$, then solve the problem in step 2 for $y$. Can this be solved for large-scale $N \geq 10^{10}$?

Comment: I think that numerical methods are not able to solve this, say for $N>10000$. You should find an explicite solution, at least to step 1, and ideally to the whole problem. What are the expressions of $f_i$ and $g$? May be should you also able to say something about your "empirical mean" function $N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i\left(x_i\right)$, can you apply the law of large numbers here?

Comment: So you be so kind and post the solution of this problem next week after your seminar? I am not able to say anything else which is constructive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88854/discussion-between-bertrand-and-learning).

Answer (score 0):

Your case fits General consensus ADMM with regularization as in [Ryan Tibshirani - Dual Methods and ADMM](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-F15/lectures/21-dual-meth.pdf) (See slide 27):

[image]

In you case you should convert the constraint into an indicator function. Then use it as part of the $ {f}_{i} $ functions.

In you case $ \boldsymbol{a}_{i] = \boldsymbol{e}_{i} $ which will make things easier.

If you want to be even more efficient, you may use General Form Consensus Optimization from [Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) (See page 53):

[image]

In this case the fact each function is a scalar function will be used to make things more efficient.

If you share specific functions ($f, g$) then I will try to implement.